# udev parameter in efistub same thing as udev config file?

Tags: linux, bootloader, kernel, udev

I want to increase the debugging level for udev at boot time. Can this be done by changing the parameter in the /etc/udev/udev.conf

Does rebuilding the initrd with mkinitcpio -p somehow embed this parameter in the boot?

I know the parameter in udev.conf is udev_log="debug" for example (or does udev_log=3 also work?)

However, somebody told me there is a kernel parameter `udev.log_priority=3` also. Does this have the same effect? I am concerned about using this parameter because I don't see it in the kernel parameters documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> I am concerned about using this parameter because I don't see it in the kernel parameters documentation.

It's not a *kernel* parameter, strictly speaking; it's a parameter that is read *from* the kernel command line by userspace processes. It is documented in the [systemd-udevd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-udevd.service.8.html) manual page.

There are many such parameters recognized by udev and/or systemd processes. (Even `root=` is read by userspace – by the initramfs '/init' program – whenever you have an initramfs.)